# Using COUNT(Distinct ) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, group-by

Here is a database schema:

```
customers (custID, firstname, familyname, town, state)  
orders (orderID, custlD, date)  
lineitems (orderID, itemlD, quantity, despatched)  
items (itemID, description, unitcost, stocklevel)  
itemSupplier (supplierID, itemlD)  
supplier (supplierID, sName, sAddress, telephoneNo, delivers)
```

Here is the question:

If we assume that the description field in the items table uses a set of pre-defined categories (e.g., tents, spades, etc), then we can answer questions like, 'how many different kinds of tent does the shop sell?' Write a SQL query to list all items for which more than one of the same kind of item is sold and to find how many different types of that item are sold (i.e., a list with colunm headings: description; 'how many types are sold').

I tried to use `DISTINCT` in `COUNT()` function like this:

```
SELECT description, count(DISTINCT itemID) AS how_many_types_are_sold
FROM items
GROUP BY description
```

I'm not sure whether it's a right use of the functions or not. Is there any advice to solve this question? Thanks in advance:D

Comment: Well have you tried running this query?

Comment: Add some sample table data, the current result and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, jarlh These are all paper works. There is no exact data. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT description, count(DISTINCT itemID) AS how_many_types_are_sold
FROM items
GROUP BY description;
```

Based on your description, this does what you want to do.  But . . . you should be using `DISTINCT` only when necessary.

There is a really good chance that a column called `itemID` in a table called `items` is actually the primary key for the table.  If so, then each row has a distinct value, and the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is redundant.  Based on this assumption, you can just count the number of rows that match:

```
SELECT description, count(*) AS how_many_types_are_sold
FROM items
GROUP BY description;
```

This is much preferred (because `count(*)` performs better than `count(distinct)`), assuming that `itemID` is unique in the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:D

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you do not need distinct in your select statement, as the group by will group every item based description which means,

```
SELECT description, count(*) AS how_many_types_are_sold FROM items GROUP BY description
```

but you can use above statement if only and if all the categories are predefined as you mentioned in your question, otherwise some not defined descriptions will be expected, in this case you need some kind of mapping table to map all the descriptions with all categories you have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:D